# CREATE USER and GRANT to create a user that can access database from Power BI

Tags: mysql, sql, powerbi, amazon-rds

I am pretty new in here and the answer might be obvious here but I am quite lost.

So, I have MySQL Database (hosted on Amazon AWS RDS). I would like to query data directly from power bi using a user (that is not the root user) with minimum privileges.

So here is the steps I did (done in MySQL Workbench):

1. I created a user named powerbi

```
CREATE USER 'powerbi'@'localhost' identified BY '12345'
```

2. I granted SELECT privilege to user

```
GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'powerbi'@'localhost'
```

3. I checked the user status using SELECT * FROM mysql.user

[Here is the output]

[image: 1]

I want to try my connection by connecting it using MySQL workbench but I encountered an error

[connecting]

[image: 2]

[connection error]

[image: 3]

When I am trying to connect to the database using Power BI, here is the error I got:
[power bi error]

[image: 4]

Any idea of what steps I missed?

Answer (score 0):

i think Your Hosting Not Allow. MySql Database Remote access.

Check four point

1. IP Address or hosting Name
2. User Name
3. Passwords
4. database Name

Comment: Is this something that should be done on AWS? Is there anyway to check it in MySQL?